# Stack Overflow JavaScript Code Editor: Members of Global Object 'window' Accessible Directly

Tags: javascript

I noticed on Stack Overflow's JavaScript code editor, the global object has many members, including the normal global browser object, `window`.

How does it offer members of `window` directly (for instance `Promise`, as seen below), when the full path is in fact `this.window.Promise`?

```js
console.log('this in top-level scope: ', this);
console.log('Promise constructor on window object, from top-level scope: ', this.window.Promise);
console.log('Still, grabbing Promise directly works: ', Promise);
```

Comment: `this === window // true`. `window` is the global scope and it has itself inside. `window.window.window.window === window // true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because what you see is actually the global `window` itself which contains a self reference:

```
this === window
window.window === window
```

Thats how it is in every browser, thats not something special of SO snippets. Therefore it doesnt matter if you access it like:

```
Promise
window.Promise
this.window.Promise
this.window.window.Promise
```

Comment: Thanks, Jonas. If what i see when logging `this` is in fact the `window` object, any idea why can't I find the `Promise` constructor on it? Shouldn't the global object implement ECMAScript defined `standard built-in functions`? If `Promise` is not on `window`, any idea where it resides?

Comment: @magnus what do you get if you do `console.log(this.Promise);`  ?

Comment: You get the `Promise` object, but if you take the logged output from `console.log(this)` and paste it in a text/code editor and do a search for `Promise`, no object is found (at least not for me). `setTimeout` and other Web APIs are visible.

Comment: It's a non-enumerable property.

Comment: @magnus I guess thats because `setTimeout` comes from a different spec as the `Promise` which is defined in the ECMA spec on the global object, and therefore one is `enumerable: true` while the other one is not (its kind of hidden)

Comment: Interesting. I did `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this));`, which prints both `enumerable`s and `non-enumerable`s, and I got all the expected matches, including `Object`, `Function`, `Promise`, etc.. The thing that threw me off here, is that in my Visual Studio Code editor (Windows box) `console.log(obj)` actually logs non-enumerables too.

Answer (score 1):

the keyword 'this' in javascript refers to the current execution context, whatever that may be.  If the current execution context is the global scope, this refers to window.